# Postgres 11 Standby never catches up

Tags: postgresql, database-replication, wal, postgresql-11

Since upgrading to Postgres 11 I cannot get my production standby server to catch up. In the logs things look fine eventually:

```
2019-02-06 19:23:53.659 UTC [14021] LOG:  consistent recovery state reached at 3C772/8912C508
2019-02-06 19:23:53.660 UTC [13820] LOG:  database system is ready to accept read only connections
2019-02-06 19:23:53.680 UTC [24261] LOG:  started streaming WAL from primary at 3C772/8A000000 on timeline 1
```

But the following queries show everything is not fine:

```
warehouse=# SELECT coalesce(abs(pg_wal_lsn_diff(pg_last_wal_receive_lsn(), pg_last_wal_replay_lsn())), -1) / 1024 / 1024 / 1024 AS replication_delay_gbytes;
 replication_delay_gbytes
-------------------------
    208.2317776754498486
(1 row)

warehouse=# select now() - pg_last_xact_replay_timestamp() AS replication_delay;
 replication_delay
-------------------
 01:54:19.150381
(1 row)
```

After a while (a couple hours) `replication_delay` stays about the same but `replication_delay_gbytes` grows, although note `replication_delay` is behind from the beginning and `replication_delay_gbytes` starts near `0`. During startup there were a number of these messages:

```
2019-02-06 18:24:36.867 UTC [14036] WARNING:  xlog min recovery request 3C734/FA802AA8 is past current point 3C700/371ED080
2019-02-06 18:24:36.867 UTC [14036] CONTEXT:  writing block 0 of relation base/16436/2106308310_vm
```

but Googling suggests these are fine.

Replica was created using repmgr by running `pg_basebackup` to perform the clone and then starting up the replica and seeing it catch up. This previously was working with Postgres 10.

Any thoughts on why this replica comes up but is perpetually lagging?

Comment: Instinct says network or disk bandwidth but I assume you are monitoring those?

Comment: Yes. That aspect is also unchanged since the upgrade (same hardware, same network, etc.).

Comment: And your delay is steadily increasing but not at the same rate as your clock? (warning - you may have to wait a while for some posts from knowledgable posters in Europe, I'm trying to make sure we have all the info we need). I'm just checking the fact that (1) it is replaying something but (2) not fast enough.

Comment: right. the `replication_delay` stays within about 3 minutes of the value posted but `replication_delay_gbytes` keeps growing. also worth noting that there's a steady stream of something like 5k transactions/minute on master generating about 1-2 GB of WAL logs per minute.

Comment: Are there any active transactions on the standby? What is `max_standby_streaming_delay` on the standby?

Comment: the default, 30s. i have noticed some monitoring queries dying because of that, however turning off the monitors and verifying no queries are running in the standby didn't help; i got the same behavior as above even when the only query was me querying pg_stat_activity to look for queries.

Comment: I think I have better isolated the cause of this issue and posted a question about it https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/233894/postgres-replication-delay-with-inserts-into-large-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not sure what the issue is/was, but I was able to get the standby caught up with these two changes:

- set `use_replication_slots=true` in the repmgr config
- set `wal_compression=on` in the postgres config

Use replication slots didn't seem to change anything other than to cause `replication_delay_gbytes` to stay roughly flat. Turing on WAL compression did help, somehow, although I'm not entirely sure how. Yes, in theory it made it possible to ship WAL files to the standby faster, but reviewing network logs I see a drop in sent/received bytes that matches the effects of compression, so it seems to be shipping WAL files at the same speed just using less network.

It still seems like there is some underlying issue at play here, though, because for example when I do `pg_basebackup` to create the standby it generates roughly 500 MB/s of network traffic, but then when it is streaming WALs after the standby finishes recovery it drops to ~250 MB/s without WAL compression and ~100 MB/s with WAL compression, but there is no decrease in network traffic after it caught up with WAL compression, so I'm not sure what's going on there that allowed it to catch up.